# Sharepoint 2013 Attaching databases from different SQL instance

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We plan to backup a SharePoint content database from Production to Test environment. The problem is, that storage on the SQL in Test isn't sufficient.

We have two SQL instances in Production, so my question now is, if we can restore the content database from one instance into the other and then mount it to a web application in the Test environment.

Example: We backup the SP content database from production SQL instance (A)  and restore it into the second production sql instance (B) . Now we attach the restored database in production SQL instance (B) and mount the database on a web application in the Test SP server.

Note: All SQL instances are same version.
Is this supported from SharePoint ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems slightly unclear. You can update it with clear wordings. Also you get help from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

What you plan to do is possible.

1. Backup your desired content database
2. Restore it to the second instance of your productive system
3. On your Test Environment mount the Content Database to the web application you want it to mount (When running "Mount-SpContentDatabase" make sure you use the correct "-DatabaseServer")

Your Mount Command should look like this:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name "[DatabaseName]" -WebApplication "[Name of WebApplication in Test]" -DatabaseServer "[Name of Instance B of your productive system]"
```

Comment: Hi SunP, the above steps worked fine for me and i was able to attach the database and database is showing correct site count. But when i try to access the sites, i am receiving page not found error.  Checked Test-SPcontentdatabase and got errors with web part missing but no orphaned sites.

Comment: Hello kumar, in your log directory there should be a file that was created when you mounted the database. Can you check if any specific errors are listed there? Are you able to get the Sites with the "Get-SPSite" command? Can you also check in CA -> "Manage Content Databases", if the Database is shown under the correct Web Application.

Comment: Hi SunP, the related web application was not created properly when I checked in IIS. Now i created the new web application and remounted the database and could see the sites successfully. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, steps u mentioned will work. But couple of things u have to keep in mind, sharing the production sql server across multiple farms not recommended for the following reasons.

- If there is an issue with one farm and causing issue on Sql, which will bring 2nd farm down.
- Make sure you have enough capacity to accommodate the load from both farms.
- If You Doing Development and their is any memory leak or bad code or bad query can cause ask resource issue and that will impact ur production farm.
- Also make sure use the unique name convention

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I am able to manage the database from different sql instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access some other page say _layouts/viewlsts.aspx or settings.aspx page and check it works.

If it does then there could be some issue with the home page.